# mapping through an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array called enquiries
Im trying to map through it like this:

```
enquiries.map(enquiry => enquiry.firstName)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: enquiries.map is not a function
```

Here is output for console.log(enquiries)

```
{enquiries: Array(2)}
  enquiries:Array(2)
  0:{_id: "5a28364d5a36f4556af34741",
     firstName: "jonny",
     surname: "rotten",
     telephoneNumber: 859937,
     gender: ""male"", …}
  1:{id: "5a283e4c5a36f4556af34742",
     firstName: "bob",
     surname: "hoskins",
     telephoneNumber: 939483948,
     gender: "male", …}
```

Comment: well the basics here is that Javascript disagrees that `enquiries` is an array, and therefore does not have any of the `Array.prototype` methods. _Why_ that is, without some more context to your code, I cannot say.

Comment: Try `enquiries.enquiries.map` - looks like `enquiries` is an object with 1 key, `enquiries`

Comment: Thanks tymeJV I already tried that.... no joy.. not sure whats going on

Comment: Try to write `console.log(typeof enquiries)` and `console.log(JSON.stringify(enquiries))` and post your result.

Answer (score 4):

The first `{enquiries: Array(2)}` implies that the logged element is an object that contains a key named `enquiries`.

So if your logged variable is also `enquiries` then you need

```
let firstNames = enquiries.enquiries.map(enquiry=>enquiry.firstName);
```

---

Also to return the `firstName` from your arrow function, you need to either use `{}` and `return` inside it, or skip the `{}` altogether for an implicit `return`.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense - but it returns an error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: @jojojohn what browser (*and version*) are you using, and how is the `enquiries` variable filled ?

Comment: Im compiling with create-react-app and rendering it in chrome

Comment: @jojojohn and is the `console.log(enquiries)` right before the `.map` ? Is it the previous command executed ? or are you logging at some other point ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have two reasons for that.
First, your "enquiries" variable is an object (but as it seems it's iteratable, that's good!).
As an object, it doesn't have the map function in its prototype.

Second, your arrow function uses curly brackets - which indicates that code should be written in.
To use the shortcut for a single value you could either rid of the curly brackets or use regular ones:

```
enquiries.map((enquiry) => (enquiry.firstName))
```

or even:

```
enquiries.map(enquiry => enquiry.firstName)
```

So for conclusion:

```
Array.from(enquiries).map(enquiry => enquiry.firstName)
```